# An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the │ argument value

Tags: terraform

I am new in Terraform, and I receive the following error when I used terraform apply in my cmd: **An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the
│ argument value.** 
Here is my code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.67.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "user1"  
  region = "eu-west-3"
  access_key = "133634"
  secret_key = "133634"
}

data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc? {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "gelistirici-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.10.0/24"
  avaliability_zone = "eu-west-3a"
}
```

- Here is my full error:

```
 Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on main.tf line 18:
│   18: data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc?{
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the
│ argument value.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about my AWS credentials, more specifically my public and private keys. Once I downloaded to them from my AWS account, the error vanished. Now the code is working w/o an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc? { ... }
```

use:

```
data "aws_vpc" "gelistirici-vpc" { ... }
```

You may also want to set the VPC on the "gelistirici-vpc" subnet, but that shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: I did but now I got the following errors:
*Error 1:

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 18, in data "aws_vpc" "gelistirici-vpc":
│   18:   id = var.vpc_id
│
│ An input variable with the name "vpc_id" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable
│ "vpc_id" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 21, in resource "aws_subnet" "gelistirici-vpc":
│   21: resource "aws_subnet" "gelistirici-vpc" {
│
│ The argument "vpc_id" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
```

Comment: ╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-1":
│   30:   vpc_id = aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc.id
│
│ A managed resource "aws_vpc" "gelistirici-vpc" has not been declared in the root module.
│
│ Did you mean the data resource data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 45, in resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-2":
│   45:   avaliability_zone = "eu-west-3a"
│
│ An argument named "avaliability_zone" is not expected here. Did you mean "availability_zone"?

Comment: Have you configured var.vpc_id? If not that error is expected. Consider replacing that with the literal id of the VPC you want to pull in as a data resource. For the second error, you will need to replace `avaliability_zone` with the correctly spelled `availability_zone`, as it says in the error message.

Comment: I did, but now I received following error:
 Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 22, in resource "aws_subnet" "gelistirici-vpc":
│   22: resource "aws_subnet" "gelistirici-vpc" {
│
│ The argument "vpc_id" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-1":
│   31:   vpc_id = aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc.id
│
│ A managed resource "aws_vpc" "gelistirici-vpc" has not been declared in the root module.

Comment: Data resources use the prefix data. `data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc.id` is what you're looking for.

Comment: In that case, I am getting the following error:  Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on main.tf line 24:
│   24: data.aws_vpc.gelistirici-vpc.id {
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the
│ argument value.

Comment: Do you feel like these errors are related to the question, or are you able to work through them by reading the error?

Comment: no, but I solved anyway.